Angular 17+ new build system and ng-packagr
I am currently upgrading from Angular 16 to Angular 18. I read on the changes that there is a new build system being implemented for the newer version.
However, most of my packages are using "ng-packagr" to build, my question is "will the new Angular build system have any impacts and or future updates to ng-packagr? Can I still be able to use ng-packagr?"
I did build my project after the upgrade; it seem like everything is build fine. But I just want to make sure.

ng-packagr is not a build system. It's basically a configuration helper for creating Angular libs (more on that).
The build system change you're probably talking about is from Webpack to Vite+ESBuild — these are bundlers. However, this migration is optional (see) and both builders are currently supported (as of Angular 18).
So this change has nothing to do with ng-packagr. I'm not sure if a bundler is used when building Angular libraries, but everything is compatible between apps and libraries even if they're built with different bundlers (except for incompatible Angular features, of course..).
